# How to call panel after completing 24 hours in javascript

Tags: java, javascript, android, datetime, time

Hi I want to open a specific panel in javascript after it completes 24 hours. I am trying to do it but its not working. Here is my code:

```
var currentTime = new Date().getTime();
var visitedTime = Get_Cookie('lastvisitedtime');
if (!visitedTime || visitedTime < (currentTime - 24*60*60*1000) ) {
    alert('visitedTime = ' + visitedTime);
    Set_Cookie("lastvisitedtime", currentTime);

}
else{
    Set_Cookie("lastvisitedtime", currentTime); //first time
}
```

but it always go to else part. How can I achive it so that it goes to if condition and show alert part.

Any help is appreciated. 
Thanks

Comment: What value does visitedTime have? Are you sure that the cookie is set and retreived successfully?

Comment: visitedTime contains the last visited time of page

Comment: If you debug or write to console or put alerts to see values of currentTime and visitedTime, what do you see?

Comment: check out my answer below for corrected code & jsfiddle demo...

Answer (score 0):

corrected code..

Steps:

1. Set lastvisitedtime cookie value to 0 in start
2. call a setInterval() method which will call itself after 1000ms. It will call timeEvent() function after 1000ms.
3. Apply a if condition to check if visitedTime is 0 or it have some valied value
4. If visitedTime have some valied time value then Apply if condition to check time difference between visitedTime & currentTime

   [DEMO jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Pj3xK/)

   ```
   // In start set cookie to null 
   setCookie("lastvisitedtime", 0);

   setInterval(function(){timeEvent()}, 1000);

   function timeEvent(){   
       var currentTime = (new Date()).getTime();
       var visitedTime = getCookie('lastvisitedtime');
       if (visitedTime != 0){
         if((currentTime - visitedTime) >= 60*1000){
            alert('visitedTime = ' + visitedTime);
            setCookie("lastvisitedtime", currentTime);
          }  
       }
      else{
           setCookie("lastvisitedtime", currentTime); //first time
      }
   }



   function getCookie(c_name)
    {
     var c_value = document.cookie;
     var c_start = c_value.indexOf(" " + c_name + "=");
     if (c_start == -1)
     {
       c_start = c_value.indexOf(c_name + "=");
    }
    if (c_start == -1)
    {
      c_value = null;
    }
    else
   {
      c_start = c_value.indexOf("=", c_start) + 1;
      var c_end = c_value.indexOf(";", c_start);
   if (c_end == -1)
   {
      c_end = c_value.length;
   }
      c_value = unescape(c_value.substring(c_start,c_end));
   }  
   return c_value;
   }

   function setCookie(c_name,value,exdays)
   {
     var exdate=new Date();
     exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
     var c_value=escape(value) + ((exdays==null) ? "" : ";        expires="+exdate.toUTCString());
     document.cookie=c_name + "=" + c_value;
   }

   function checkCookie()
   {
      var username=getCookie("username");
      if (username!=null && username!="")
    {
       alert("Welcome again " + username);
    }
    else 
    {
       username=prompt("Please enter your name:","");
       if (username!=null && username!="")
      {
         setCookie("username",username,365);
      }
    }
   }
   ```

Comment: if (!visitedTime && (curentTime - visitedTime) == 60*1000) ) { this condition is always returning flase value. for testing purpose i change it to 1 min

Comment: Thanks I check n let u kw